# How to change parentheses to brackets

Tags: python-3.x, list, return, list-comprehension

a newbie in Python here. I'm trying to create a table which takes in list n numbers and outputs n+1, n+2 and n+3 rows.

Here's my code:

```
def addition_table(numbers):
    add_one = [ num + 1 for num in numbers ]
    add_two = [ num + 2 for num in numbers ]
    add_three = [ num + 3 for num in numbers ]
    return add_one, add_two, add_three
```

my output for ([1]):

([2],[3],[4])

is there a way to change the output to [[2],[3],[4]]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to return those values inside a list.

```
def addition_table(numbers):
    add_one = [ num + 1 for num in numbers ]
    add_two = [ num + 2 for num in numbers ]
    add_three = [ num + 3 for num in numbers ]
    return [add_one, add_two, add_three]
```